# HTML form does not always submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form which sometimes submits and sometimes doesn't. The form is submitted using a button which validates the form using javascript and then submits it also using javascript like so:

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf-token">
  <input type="text" name="1">
  <input type="text" name="2">
  <button onclick="validateForm()">
</form>

<script>
  function validateForm() {
    // Validate rules here
    document.forms['my-form'].submit();
  }
</script>
```

It is pretty straight forward. The data is then sent to the sever, the csrf token is checked and then the input is saved into a database. I'm trying to understand why the form does not submit all the time. Sometimes when I click the submit button, the page just reloads and the data is gone when other times the form is saved to the database and I'm redirected to the next page.

From what I can guess, I believe this may have something to do with expiration. If start the form and leave it too long, it does not submit. Every time I submit the form right away it submits. However sometimes when I leave the form too long it does submit.

You can imagine how frustrating this could be as data entered is sometimes lost. What could be the cause of this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The innards of your `validateForm` are likely important, can you share the full function?

Comment: check the debug console in your browser.

Comment: @Whymarrh I have the full unsimplified version here: pastebin.com/zG0zWLJc

Comment: @BenRowe I have, unfortunately, nothing appears.

Comment: @PavSidhu please add it to the original question (and reduce it to a minimal example if possible)

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that the form isn't submitting? If you check the server log, do you see an entry for the form? The "expiration" issue sounds like it may be something to do with a server-side session expiring.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution:*
Add `type="button"` attribute to your `<button>`. This will stop the form from treating your button like a `submit` button.

*Explanation:*
"Sometimes it works" often means you have a race condition. Your race condition is between your JavaScript and default browser behavior. The default `type` attribute of a `<button>` is `submit`. The form in your sample code does not have an `action` or a `method` attribute. With those conditions the form's default behavior will be to do a `GET` for the current url when your button is clicked. The button click will also run your javascript. But depending on how quickly the default behavior reloads the page (or how slow your validations are) your javascript `submit` may or may not get hit.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, you are using a CSRF token. CSRF tokens have an expiration time based on the framework/CMS that you use. This is pretty much configurable.

Now what happens is, when the CSRF token expires, the input is rejected by the server. This **might be** the case for you. To check this, keep the form open and submit after a long time, if the same issue repeats itself, use the below solution or else this is not your case.

A simple solution for this would be to increase the expiration time of the CSRF token and check if the phenomena repeats.